# How to Use .substr() method on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean

I'd like to use substr() in Mongoose like this :

```
nim = req.body.nim;
var prodi  = nim.substr(3,5);
```

But it returns :

> TypeError: nim.substr is not a function

On my console, how to fix it?

The response body is:

```
{ nama: 'Ambikapathi', email: 'ambi@me.id', nim: 14520244010, password: '14520244010', repassword: '14520244010' }
```

Comment: What is in `req.body`? The error would indicate there is no such property as `nim` there.

Comment: req.body.nim is a String value from input

Comment: Can you include the contents of console logging `req.body` please.

Comment: { nama: 'Ambikapathi',
  email: 'ambi@me.id',
  nim: 14520244010,
  password: '14520244010',
  repassword: '14520244010' }

Comment: When I use substring() on angular, it's work. But when I try it on the backend, returns an error.

Comment: `nim` is a numeric value. It's clearly shown as such in the data you dropped in the comment. `nim.toString().substr(3,5)` works just as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to use [string prototype substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), not [mongo's one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/). And it fail b/c your data contain **integer** instead of **string** there:

```
{ nama: 'Ambikapathi', email: 'ambi@me.id', nim: 14520244010, password: '14520244010', repassword: '14520244010' }
```

something like this:

```
nim = req.body.nim.toString();
```

should fix your issue.

UPDATE (by @ŞükSefHam): or it's maybe the issue that `nim` was defined somewhere else with default non-string value

Comment: All of req.body=string ;so we dont need req.body.xx.toString().You send data numerically.Always typeof req.body==="string".You can try.

Comment: @ŞükSefHam, yeah, but from the comments it's obvious that the case is that `nim` is integer `14520244010`, idk, maybe some additional middleware or something...

Comment: May be.One more:may be var nim already defined;I have encountered an error similar to this.

Comment: @ŞükSefHam, yep, may be. As you already familiar with this case, why don't you try to answer, or comment to clarify?

Comment: I write on phone:)

Comment: you can answer this question by subtracting from my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like nim is a number and not a string. Try this 
 `nim.toString().substr(3,5);`